# TypeError when calling sendKeys in CasperJS

Tags: coffeescript, casperjs

I am trying to use coffeescript and casperjs (1.0.0-RC4) to complete a tedious login and want to fill in a form that uses the name attribute for it's fields (e.g. `<input type='text' name='accountname'></input>`). I originally was going to use @fill to complete the form, but was having issues (I'm guessing) because the id attribute isn't in the input tag. So, I decided to use the @sendKeys method, but it's throwing a really confusing error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.sendKeys('#accountname', developerAccountName)')`

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong in this code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env casperjs

developerAccountName = "user@user.com"
developerPassword = "password"

casper = require("casper").create(
    verbose: true
    logLevel: "debug"
    );

casper.start "http://www.example.com"

casper.thenClick "#content .maincontent .image.first a"

casper.thenClick ".button.blue"

casper.then ->
    if (@exists "#accountname") and (@exists "#accountpassword")
        @sendKeys '#accountname', developerAccountName
        @sendKeys '#accountpassword', developerPassword
        @click "form .signin-button"
    else
        @echo "Couldn't find the fields"

casper.run ->
    @echo "Complete."
```

Comment: Hey @muistooshort - I gave that a shot and the error is now that `_this` doesn't have the methods.
`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '_this.exists("#accountname")')`

Comment: This is resolved - they added sendKeys to CasperJS in 1.0.0.RC5.

Answer (score 3):

The sendKeys method wasn't available until 1.0.0.RC5